# Добавление информации в пустой блок

Tags: javascript, vue.js

У меня есть шесть блоков, в двух есть информация, в четырех ее нету, сверху есть input в который можно ввести информацию и нажавши на иконку введенная информация будет пушиться , но у меня просто создается блок новый, то есть седьмой, не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы допустим информация шла в третий блок, ввел еще раз информацию, она шла в четвертый и тд ?

```js
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data() {
      return {
         addpepleofhouse: '',
         loaves: [
            {name: 'Kastyn', lname: 'L.', passport: 1414234234}, 
            {name: 'Tupe', lname: 'F.', passport: 231223434}, 
            {empty: true}, 
            {empty: true}, 
            {empty: true}, 
            {empty: true}, 
         ],
      }
   },
   methods: {
      Massageforpeople() {
         this.addinput = false;
         this.tempaddpeople = true;
         setTimeout(() => {
            this.addpeople = true;
            this.tempaddpeople = false;
         }, 2000);
         this.loaves.push({
            passport: this.addpepleofhouse
         })
      }
   },
});
```

```css
.people__slots {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 924px;
  height: 212px;
}
.people__item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  border-radius: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="" id="app">
      <input type="text" v-model="addpepleofhouse" class="peoplehouseadd" placeholder="Паспорт"> 
      <img src="./img/plus_icon.svg" class="peopleaddimg" @click="Massageforpeople()">
      <div class="people__slots">
        <div class="people__item" v-for="(loave, index) in loaves">
           <div v-if="!loave.empty" class="people__item-pasport">{{loave.passport}}</div>
           <div class="item__blokc" v-if="loave.empty">
              Пусто
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо при добавлении проверять ваш массив на наличие элементов c ключом empty. Элемент найден, меняете, если нет, добавляете(ну или делаете другую логику, если допустим вам надо только 6 элементов)

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      addpepleofhouse: '',
      loaves: [
        {name: 'Kastyn', lname: 'L.', passport: 1414234234},
        {name: 'Tupe', lname: 'F.', passport: 231223434},
        {empty: true},
        {empty: true},
        {empty: true},
        {empty: true},
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    Massageforpeople() {
      this.addinput = false;
      this.tempaddpeople = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.addpeople = true;
        this.tempaddpeople = false;
      }, 2000);
      let idx
      const find = this.loaves.find((item, index) => {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty('empty')) {
          idx = index;
          return true;
        }
      })
      if (find) {
        this.loaves[idx] = { passport: this.addpepleofhouse }
      } else {
        this.loaves.push({
          passport: this.addpepleofhouse
        })
      }
    }
  },
});
```

Отдельно стоит подумать над тем, что бы изначально сохранять индекс первого пустого элемента, что бы избегать перебора массива. А сам индекс увеличивать при изменении.

Я бы сделал так:

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      addpepleofhouse: '',
      loaves: [
        {name: 'Kastyn', lname: 'L.', passport: 1414234234},
        {name: 'Tupe', lname: 'F.', passport: 231223434},
        {empty: true},
        {empty: true},
        {empty: true},
        {empty: true},
      ],
      loavesIdx: 2,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    Massageforpeople() {
      this.addinput = false;
      this.tempaddpeople = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.addpeople = true;
        this.tempaddpeople = false;
      }, 2000);
      
      if (this.loaves.length !== this.loavesIdx + 1) {
        this.loaves[this.loavesIdx] = { passport: this.addpepleofhouse }
      } else {
        this.loaves.push({
          passport: this.addpepleofhouse
        })
      }
      this.loavesIdx++;      
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Когда я использовал первый варианта, я вписал цифры, нажал на картинку 5 раз, до этого в пустых блоках было пусто, после пуша 5-ого блока, у них пропал текст с "Пусто" и туда добавилась введенная информация

Comment: Вроде как вы именно этого поведения хотели достичь?